# how to copy values from the same named ranges from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an extensive Workbook which exists in multiple versions that contains hundreds of named ranges.
I want to write a macro that transfers user input data entered to certain named ranges from one instance of the book to another.
The named ranges in the book follow a certain convention, for the purposes of this macro i want to copy the values (which are constants) of all named ranges starting with `"in_*"` and `"resetRange_*"`

the macro is supposed to:

1. open the source book (which has mostly the same named ranges defined as the current book)
2. iterate over all named ranges of the source book and find the ones `like "in_*" or "resetRange_*"`
3. copy the values at the named ranges from the source book to the current book (even if the names refer to areas)

my main questions are:

- how do i copy correctly?  the current implementation does not work
- is there a better way to test whether a source name is still present in the current book?

the named ranges in question all are scoped to the workbook.

The issue that the macro runs error free but does not paste any values. the named ranges of the  current book remain empty while the source book contains data
´

```
Public Sub TransferInputDataFromOtherTool()
                Dim sourceBook As Workbook
                Dim bookPath As Variant

'get source book
bookPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("(*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Select source tool:")
If VarType(bookPath) = vbString Then
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(bookPath)
End If

On Error GoTo Cleanup

'@TODO transfer ranges _
    resetRange_* _
    in_*
'retrieving data
For Each n In sourceBook.Names
    On Error Resume Next
    rangeName = n.Name
    boola = ThisWorkbook.Names(n.Name)
    If boola Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rangeName Like "in_*" _
           or rangeName like "resetRange_*" Then
            'check for allow edit
            On Error Resume Next
            sourceBook.Activate
            source_value = n.refersToRange.Value
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Range(rangeName).Value = source_value
            'Debug.Print rangeName, source_value
            'Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.source
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        ' deleting all in_-values
    End If
Next n

'@TODO transfer tables
'ExcelHandling.EnableInteractivity

Cleanup:
On Error Resume Next
sourceBook.Close
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: so where is the failure or the issue?

Comment: Do you correctly loop through all the names? If you debug.print the named ranges before checking your conditions, do you get all of them correctly? You may need to define the sheet of the range [Sheet1.Range("thisrange")] depending on how the range was declared.

Comment: for some reason, `source_value = Range(rangeName).Value` was always empty. i replaced it with `= n.refersToRange.Value` which seems to work (except for disconnected ranges with multiple areas)

Comment: Do you want to create/define Names into the new workbook? Or are you only trying to extract data?

Comment: the names exist in both books, i just want to copy the values from one book to the corresponding range in the second book

Comment: Looks like a lot of places where you should be using `Set`. also, there's no error-handling, so you don't really know if it's failing with errors or not.  Also, `Activate` is both slow and error-prone, so should be avoided in macros.

Comment: any suggestions on how to do it without `activate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code sample to help. Please turn on `Option Explicit` and define all your VBA variables. See if this works for you:

> **EDIT:** added range check to detect more than one cell in a given range, then to copy each cell

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferInputDataFromOtherTool()
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim filename As String
    Dim definedVariable As Name
    Dim singleCell As Range
    Dim singleCellLocation As String

    '--- the destination book is the currently active workbook from the user's perspective
    Set destWB = ThisWorkbook

    '--- source book from which to copy the data from - user selected
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("(*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Select source tool:")
    If filename = "False" Then
        '--- the user selected cancel
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf filename = destWB.Path & "\" & destWB.Name Then
        MsgBox "You can't open the same file that's already active. Select another file.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    End If

    Debug.Print "values coming from " & filename
    For Each definedVariable In srcWB.Names
        If (definedVariable.Name Like "in_*") Or (definedVariable.Name Like "resetRange_*") Then
            '--- if the source/destination range is only a single cell, then
            '    it's an easy one-to-one copy
            Debug.Print definedVariable.Name & " refers to " & definedVariable.RefersTo;
            If destWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange.Cells.Count = 0 Then
                '--- do nothing
            ElseIf destWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Debug.Print " source value = '" & destWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange.Value & "'";
                Debug.Print " overwritten with '" & srcWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange.Value & "'"
                destWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange = srcWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange.Value
            Else
                '--- the source/target range has multiple cells, either contiguous
                '    or non-contiguous. so loop and copy...
                Debug.Print vbTab & "multiple cells in range..."
                For Each singleCell In destWB.Names(definedVariable.Name).RefersToRange
                    singleCellLocation = "'" & singleCell.Parent.Name & "'!" & singleCell.Address
                    Debug.Print vbTab & " source value = '" & singleCell.Value & "'";
                    Debug.Print "' overwritten with '" & srcWB.Sheets(singleCell.Parent.Name).Range(singleCell.Address).Value & "'"
                    singleCell.Value = srcWB.Sheets(singleCell.Parent.Name).Range(singleCell.Address).Value
                Next singleCell
            End If
        End If
    Next definedVariable

    srcWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set srcWB = Nothing
    Set destWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much! I only ran into one problem where the named range refers to a tessellated range of multiple areas. In this case, `refersToRange` doesnt work, even though the ranges have the same areas

Comment: The edited code above works for both contiguous and non-contiguous named ranges. I used the `.Count` property to determine if the named range has more than one value.